# How to recognize a kind of keyboards?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app on android now. it is connected 2 bluetooth devices as keyborad. if the keyboard press "A", I want to recognize a specific keyboard that send the key event "A". How to find the device when it received the key event.

example)

```
switch ( keyCode ) {   case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
```

> How can I recognize the sending event keyboard? My app wants to
>   capture it.

Comment: I don't think that you can do it. I don't think that 3rd party apps should know which keyboard I am using.

Comment: Doesn't sound possible to me. Physical keyboard sure. But smartphone keyboards? Never heard if that's ever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KeyboardEvent.getDeviceId().  That will tell you which one its from, if all you need to know is if its from one or the other.  It can't be used to tell much else.